# Can't run Android Emulator in Android Studio. Its loading forever

Tags: android, emulation, haxm

I can't run android emulator in android studio. Im using Android 5.1 x86 Virtual Device. I have already installed HAXM ( Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager ) but the issue is still there. Its showing following error messages:

```
WARNING: init: Missing WGL extension WGL_ARB_make_current_read
emulator: device fd:628
emulator: error code:31
emulator: Failed to create vm ffffffff
HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: Failed to create HAX VM
emulator: warning: opening audio output failed
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check
```

I had faced similar issue before in another system but installing HAXM resolved the issue. Can someone help me out??

Answer (score 0):

You've enabled HAXM in your bios already? I had massive performance problems with the default android emulator so I downloaded and installed Genymotion with Virtual Box. Have had no issues since.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try that.